# How do I add other swing components in a specific swing tabbed pane?

Tags: java, swing

I have just started learning Java Swing and I am making a application form sort of project and I want to add more components like buttons,text areas and other in specific tab but I am not able to.
The code is given below:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
public class TabbedPaneExample {
    JFrame f;
    TabbedPaneExample(){
        f=new JFrame("Hotel Appication Form");
        JTextArea ta=new JTextArea(400,400);
        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        p1.add(ta);
        JPanel p2=new JPanel();
        JPanel p3=new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane tp=new JTabbedPane();
        tp.setBounds(39,20,500,500);
        tp.add("form",p1);
        tp.add("preferences",p2);
        tp.add("FaQ's",p3);
        f.add(tp);
        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setVisible(true);

        //JButton
        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
        b.setBounds(50,50,30,20);
        f.add(b);
        //JLabel

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TabbedPaneExample();
    }
  }
```

The screenshot of the output is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBPX1.png)

Comment: *"I have just started learning Java Swing and I am making a application form"* While it is intuitively obvious that a newbie should not jump into GUI development, the code speaks louder than intuition. 1) `JTextArea ta=new JTextArea(400,400);` Those aren't pixels, they're columns and rows. Be sure to check the Java docs for constructors being used. 2) `tp.setBounds(39,20,500,500);` Nope, that's just a guess. Size the components appropriately (see point (1)), add them using relevant layouts and constraints, then `pack()` the frame to fit. 3) `f.setSize(600,600);` see point (2) re `pack()` ..

Comment: .. 4) `f.add(b);` This is the wrong time to be adding components. Correct order: a) add **all** components. b) `pack()` to size. c) Call `setVisible(true);` 5) `new TabbedPaneExample();` All Swing / AWT GUIs should be started and updated on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: @Wulf I tried that earlier but that didn't work

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's right I shouldn't have jumped but I was bound to,because it's an assignment given by my teacher and I need to submit it anyhow,so no basics cleared therefore I don't have any idea how swing works,but once I submit my assignment I will start from scratch and thanks for your suggestions,I'll work on them from now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this code example simple frame with tabbed panel and simple components in each tab.
Your problem was incorrect adding components to JPanel. 
Hope that helps you!

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhJqr.png)  [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j55aC.png)

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        // Create and set up the window.
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Split Pane Example");

        // Display the window.
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // set grid layout for the frame
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("TextField");

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        panel2.add(textField);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab1", panel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab2", panel2);

        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting code without an explanation is not an answer. A good answer will: 1) explain what the problem is. In this case only a single component can be added to a tab and 2) explain the solution. In this case create a panel and add other components to the panel. Then the panel can be added to the tab.

Comment: @William Thank you very much!I have been working on your code now and I have been able to add the components which I needed but all the components are going in one flow,I want the components to be placed in a new line, all the components are getting wrapped which I don't want to.If it's possible for you,can you help me out?I will post the code then.

Comment: Yes, I can try. So mark question complete and post new one) Even maybe more people want to help you in your question.

Comment: @William Okay then, I will be marking this as complete and posting that as a new question.